# Far aar from multiple aar files

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I have a project with three modules - LibraryOne, LibraryTwo and LibraryThree.

LibraryOne is dependent on both LibraryTwo and LibraryThree. When I build this project, I get three aar files for each of the module in their respective build files. 
I want to build a single aar file containing all the files of all three modules and then I want to upload this single aar file on Maven.

I have already referred this : 
https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar/blob/master/fat-aar.gradle

It is not working. I am using Gradle 3.0. Is there any way by which I can achieve that? I am just stuck on this since last one week. A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you tried out fat-aar, did you also changed your 'compile project ...' to 'embedded project ...' in your apps build.gradle?

Comment: Yeah I did. The problem is that it is supported only till gradle 2.3 but I am using gradle 3.0 so it is not working. Atleast I think thats why it is not working.

Comment: I had a deeper look into it, you are right. Fat-aar only supports until gradle 2.3.3. So I fear that the qickest solution would be to downgrade your project to 2.3.3

Comment: Thanks bro...Can you please elaborate on the longer solution? If you have any idea about it.